# How to solve this linear programming minimization problem with the BigM method

Tags: linear-programming, big-m

Given this minimization problem:
$$z=100x_1+77x_2+80x_3\\10x_1+7x_2+2x_3 \geq 12\\2x_1+3x_2+4x_3 \geq 3\\x_1+2x_2+x_3 \geq 1\\x_1,x_2,x_3 \geq 0$$
After adding artificial variables:
$$z-100x_1-77x_2-80x_3-MR_1-MR_2-MR_3=0\\10x_1+7x_2+2x_3-s_1+R_1=12\\2x_1+3x_2+4x_3-s_2+R_2=3\\x_1+2x_2+x_3-s_3+R_3=1$$
What do you do from here?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. If the question you mentioned is homework, you should read the community policy (for posting homework) to expect someone answer your question. B.T.W maybe you wanted to see this [link](https://cbom.atozmath.com/CBOM/Simplex.aspx?q=sm) to understand how the simplex method works with the big-m method.

Comment: @A.Omidi, could you provide me with a link to the community policy? I've been looking for the link, but I couldn't find it. I also Googled "OR.SE community policy", but nothing useful came up.

Comment: The homework policy is over on the meta site: https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/can-i-ask-a-homework-question-on-or-se.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you know the Simplex method, start out with $R_1=12$, $R_2=3$, $R_4=1$ as your initial basic feasible solution and crank out simplex pivots, treating $M$ as if it were $\infty$. If you prefer, you can set $M$ to some really large finite number. The key is that if $M$ is large enough, the first few pivots you do will boot the artificial variables out of the basis. Optionally, as they drop out of the basis you can eliminate them from the problem (delete their columns from the simplex tableau), as they will never reenter the basis.